# RunningAppProcessInfo list contains only one data

Tags: android

I was trying to get all running apps on my phone, I use below code to get Running processes,

```
 List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningList= am.getRunningAppProcesses();
      if(runningList!=null && runningList.size()>0){
          Log.d("List Size",""+runningList.size());
      }
```

But the list contains only one app process in Nexus4 and Moto G which running 5.1 OS, But when i tested the same on Sony Z 5.0 os and emulator it showing the right list(70 in Sony z and 16 in emulator).

Why in nexus4 it not listing all the running process.

Comment: They probably tightened this down for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare, maybe, is there any other way to get running process, in one of my other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453283/how-to-get-value-of-mlaunchcount-from-usagestats-api-class) i was able to get mLaunchCount using java reflection, but the field not giving the proper count.

Comment: It works fine in my Nexus 4 running 5.1OS..

Comment: @shhp will you share your part of code? My code is working on 5.1 emulator and in sony but not on the nexus and moto g.

Comment: The code is same as yours.

Comment: @shhp, ok... thanks.