# Why UsageStats.mLaunchCount is not accessible in IDE?

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I have all permissions in place and can get the list of apps, and their usage stats as a list of UsageStats instances. UsageStats has a public field called mLaunchCount, added on API 22 (based on git history of the file). Now I want to access this if the phone is running API 22+, but when I try to use it, the IDE complains `Cannot resolve symbol mLaunchCount`. If I try to access it via reflection, it works.

So basically this does not compile:

```
Log.d("test", "Count: " + usageStat.mLaunchCount);
```

While this does:

```
Field mLaunchCount = UsageStats.class.getDeclaredField("mLaunchCount");
int launchCount = (Integer)mLaunchCount.get(usageStat);
Log.d("Test", "Count: " + launchCount);
```

Any idea what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `mLaunchCount` is not part of the Android SDK. In [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/usage/UsageStats.java), it is marked with the `@hide` annotation, used for things that are `public` for Java reasons but are not part of the SDK.

Comment: You are right, it seems that's the reason. I had noticed the @ hide but thought that's to exclude it from Javadocs only, but it seems @ hide does more than that (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/697716), and it's only accessible via reflection!

Comment: @m.hashemian: More importantly, there is no guarantee that this field will exist on all relevant Android builds, including those from device manufacturers and custom ROM developers.

Comment: True, has to be used considering it might not exist.